# Laravel and oracle connection

Tags: oracle, laravel-5, database-connection

I am trying to configure laravel to work with oracle database, I am trying to use Yajra for my connection but I get this error every time I try to run my application.

> FatalThrowableError in Oci8.php line 449: Fatal error: Call to
>   undefined function Yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()

If anyone can help me fix this i will be extremely grateful...

Answer (score 1):

### It because your php do not support oci8!

#### if you use Windows:

Download `instantclient-basic-windows` from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen)
Ccreate folder

```
cd E:/wamp64/bin
mkdir oracle
```

Move downloaded instantclient package into /oracle

```
mv instantclient-* E:/wamp64/bin/oracle
unzip instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
```

Add `instantclient_xx` to your `Path` and Edit `php.ini`

Uncomment them

```
extension=php_oci8_12c.dll
extension=php_odbc.dll
```

restart your wamp you'll see the `oci8`

```
<?
  phpinfo().
```

#### if you use **Linux**:

Download `instantclient-basic-linux` and `instantclient-sdk-linux` from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen), and unzip it in a dir.

```
mkdir /opt/oracle
mv instantclient-* /opt/oracle
unzip instantclient-basic-linux-x86-64-11.2.0.2.0
unzip instantclient-sdk-linux-x86-64-11.2.0.2.0

mv instantclient_11_2 instantclient
cd /opt
chown -R root:www-data /opt/oracle
echo /opt/oracle/instantclient > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient
ldconfig


cd /opt/oracle/instantclient
ln -s libclntsh.so.* libclntsh.so
ln -s libocci.so.* libocci.so
```

you neet to input 'instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient'

```
pecl install oci8
```

after finish.check if you have pci8.so in directory like `/usr/lib/php/20151012`

```
cd /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/
vi oci.ini // extension=oci8.so
cd /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/
ln -s /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/oci.ini 20-oci.ini
```

append path

```
vi /etc/environment
# append
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
export TNS_ADMIN="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
export ORACLE_BASE="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE
```

Finally

```
service php7.0-fpm restart
```